# finding the percentage > x with r

Tags: r

Trying to locate the names of countries in my data.frame where the most spoken language is not an official language. My columns `data.frame` is World. The column `country.y` is the name column of all the countries. Column `isOfficial` has data in it that is 't' or 'false' representing that the official language is 'true' or 'false'. Another column is percentage representing what percentage of a language is spoken.  So far this is what I came up with.

```
subset(World$name.y, World$isOfficial != 't' & World$percentage > 50)
```

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the data (with say, the output of `str(World)` or `str(World[ , c("country.y", "isOfficial", "percentage")])`) to enable contributors track the class of your variables little more clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following R-Code for subsetting:

```
World[World$isOfficial != 't' & World$percentage > 50, "country.y"]
```

And in case isOfficial is type logical, I would try this R-code:

```
World[!(World$isOfficial) & World$percentage > 50, "country.y"]
```

Comment: Here is what came out `> World[World$isOfficial != 't' & World$percentage > 50, "country.y"]`
NULL

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
n_var <- 24
country <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = n_var )]
pcnt <- runif(min=0,max=1,n=n_var)

world_data <- data.frame(country,pcnt) %>% 
  mutate(
    is_official=ifelse(pcnt>0.5,"Y","N")
  ) %>% 
  filter(is_official=="Y")
```